# How to call a function defined in the controller inside of the view?

Tags: angularjs

I know I can display a scope variable value by doing:

```
<div> This is my var value: {{myVar}} </div>
```

Suppose I have this function

```
$scope.displayVal = function(){
         return myVar+5;
};
```

Is there a way to call it in a similar way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<div>{{displayVal()}}</div>
```

or

```
<div ng-bind="displayVal()"></div>
```

If you use Controller as syntax

```
<div ng-controller="YourController as vm">
    <div>{{vm.displayVal()}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: how to pass an argument to the function ?

Answer (score 1):

It can be used directly like a function:

```
<div>{{displayVal()}}</div>
```

If you are initializing some values and want to call on page load then

```
<div ng-init="displayVal()"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your function is declared in the scope, you can call it normally in (what I assume is) your view; for example:

```
// code in the controller
$scope.myVar = 10;

$scope.displayVal = function(){
  return myVar + 5;
};

// code in the view
<input type="text" ng-model="displayVal()" /> // 15 will appear in the box
```

You can also call the function within a button; as to where the value will appear, I'll leave it to you:

```
<input type="button" value="Display Value" ng-click="displayVal()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

On a side note this is how you would create the function:

```
$scope.displayVal = function displayVal(){
         return myVar+5;
};
```

After the key word function you would need to enter the name of the function.